# C# OpenSource POP3 class with SSL support?

Tags: c#, pop3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading Email using Pop3 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c)

Can anyone recommend a good POP3 library for C#?  I'm surprised there isn't one in the .NET framework simliar to SMTPClient.

SSL support would be nice so that it could be used w/ Gmail.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c

Comment: I wrote a library, let me try and dig it up.

Comment: Um, it appears this question has been flagged as a duplicate, yet the links to the duplicate say Page Not Found.