# C# Fetch all email via POP3

Tags: c#, email, pop3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading Email using Pop3 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c)

How can I fetch/download all email (preferably as MailMessage) via POP3 from a mailserver using C#?

Answer (score 0):

.NET BCL does not have POP3 client class built in so you'd have to search for a third-party one. See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/info/search.aspx?artkw=c%23+pop3) for a list of those.