# asp.net assemblies processing incoming email - what's possible?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, email

I've done plenty of outbound email processing via both SQLServer and .net web apps. But in terms of what I can do to respond to incoming email I'm starting from scratch and looking for an overview of how an asp.net (preferably examples specific to mvc apps) assembly can use input from inbound email using resources native to IIS7/winserver08.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could to start with [A POP3 Client in C# .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/despop3client.aspx). This previous question can also help: [Reading Email using Pop3 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really anything IIS7/Windows 2008/MVC specific you do with regards to reading inbound mail. As [Rubens pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233832/asp-net-assemblies-processing-incoming-email-whats-possible/2233854#2233854), just go find a good .NET managed code POP3 (and IMAP if required) library.