# connect to pop3.live.com using TCPClient getting time out error

Tags: c#, email, pop3, mail-server

i am writing a program that will connect to a hotmail email account a pop all of the emails to my windows form using C# but when i try and set up the enital connecting using TCPClient i get this error message

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 65.55.32.247:110

here is the code i am using to connect to

```
public TcpClient Server;
        public NetworkStream NetStrm;
        public StreamReader  RdStrm;
 Server = new TcpClient("pop3.live.com", 110);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong port. Use 995.

For further help working with streams to read POP3 mail, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440151/reading-a-pop3-server-with-only-tcpclient-and-streamwriter-streamreadersolved).