# Trouble getting email attachment from Exchange

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

I am getting the error message “The remote server returned an error: (501) Not Implemented.” when I try to use the HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() using the GET Method to get an email attachment from exchange. I have tried to change the HttpVersion and don’t think it is a permissions issue since I can search the inbox.

I know my credentials are correct as they are used to get HREF using the HttpWebRequest.Method = Search on the inbox (https://mail.mailserver.com/exchange/testemailaccount/Inbox/).

HREF = https://mail.mailserver.com/exchange/testemailaccount/Inbox/testemail.EML/attachment.csv

Sample Code:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)  HttpWebRequest.CreateHREF);                
req.Method = "GET";
req.Credentials = this.mCredentialCache;
string data = string.Empty;
using (WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
{
    Encoding enc = Encoding.Default;
    if (resp == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Response contains no information.");
    }

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        data = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. Try to use POP3 protocol instead of HTTP. You can try to implement this yourself (see ["How to POP3 in C#"](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4071/how-to-pop3-in-c/) for example) or you can use ready-made POP3 library with SSL support ([POP3Client](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/despop3client.aspx) for example) or take a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c)
2. Also your error probably because of not handling https connections. Try to add this code:

   ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new AcceptAllCertificatePolicy();

Here is class implementation:

```
internal class AcceptAllCertificatePolicy : ICertificatePolicy
{
    public AcceptAllCertificatePolicy()
    {
    }
    public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint sPoint, X509Certificate cert,
    WebRequest wRequest, int certProb)
    {
        //Allways accept
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using WebDAV against Exchange 2007.  By default in Exchange 2007, WebDAV isn't enabled.  So you can either:

1) Enable WebDAV on your Exchange 2007 Server.

2) Switch to using Exchange Web Services.

I would recommend Option 2 since you are using C# since there is the [Managed EWS API](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C3342FB3-FBCC-4127-BECF-872C746840E1&displaylang=en&displaylang=en) which make this kind of task much simpler than using WebDAV.  It also allows you to eventually target Exchange 2010 where WebDAV has been removed completely.