# .Net POP3 client

Tags: .net, pop3

.net has a SMTP client for sending mail
but no pop3 client for reading mail.
Ive used WEBDAV before, but I really want a simple pop3 or imap client thats stable

I know there seems to be 10000 of examples, but why no offical .net client if they made a SMTP client

any thoughts?

Comment: See [Reading Email using Pop3 in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

[The F#.NET Journal](http://www.ffconsultancy.com/products/fsharp_journal/?so) article *[An e-mail client in F#](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2010/04/e-mail-client-in-f.html)* (31st March 2010) describes how you can write your own in just a few lines of F# code, centered around the following sequence expression:

```
> let receive =
    seq { use client = new Sockets.TcpClient(Server.pop3.addr, Server.pop3.port)
          use stream = client.GetStream()
          use reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream)
          let rec readToDot() =
            let line = reader.ReadLine()
            if line <> "." then line + "\n" + readToDot() else ""
          reader.ReadLine() |> ignore
          use writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(stream)
          let write (line: string) =
            writer.Write(line + "\n")
            writer.Flush()
          write "USER myname"
          reader.ReadLine() |> ignore // +OK Password required.
          write "PASS mypassword"
          reader.ReadLine() |> ignore // +OK logged in.
          write "STAT"
          let stat = reader.ReadLine() // +OK <message count> <total size>
          for i in 1 .. int (stat.Split[|' '|]).[1] do
            write(sprintf "RETR %d" i)
            reader.ReadLine() |> ignore // +OK <message size> octets follow.
            match readToDot() |> parse with
            | Some msg -> yield msg
            | None -> ()
          write "QUIT"
          reader.ReadLine() |> ignore };;
val receive : seq<msg>
```

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/) is the library I used.  It was very easy to use, didn't have any problems with it.