# Authenticate in Office 365 without show ui

Tags: c#, ms-office, office365

I am trying to build a web-service to use office 365 email and I want to sign in using the code not by showing the Microsoft UI sign in windows.

I am using office 365 API to get the mails from this account So any ideas how can I do this by code ?

It doesn't have to be using office 365 API I can use get methods if there is a way to send the username and password in the get request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use POP3 to retrieve emails from Office 365 or any email server that supports the protocol.

You would need to poll for new messages however. IMAP supports pushing new messages but you'd need to use a third party component.

[Here are the Office 365 POP and IMAP settings](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/settings-for-pop-and-imap-access-for-office-365-for-business-or-microsoft-exchange-accounts-HA102908389.aspx)
[Here is a quick link to a question about POP Clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149892/net-pop3-client)