# Download/Delete mails from pop3 account in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, email, download, pop3

I have this WCF application which is hosted as a windows service. This service has to download mails which have CSV attached to them from a pop3 account. After getting that CSV I have to delete that mail from the pop3 account so that it is not downloaded again. How can I do it?

Please help.

Comment: Are you using a pop3 library - which one? - or trying to implement the pop3 protocol yourself? I'm guessing C#? There's library suggestions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c

Comment: I am trying to implement pop3 by myself in c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send `DELE 1` command

If the message you want to delete has the ID 1

Look at [this class](http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/52373#541738) for more answers.

Comment: I am sending DELE 1 and i am getting the response +OK message 1 marked for deletion, but deletion is not taking place.

Comment: This works, thanks. Added you a point. This should have been marked as an answer.