# C# POP3 protocol solution

Tags: c#, .net, pop3

I need to read data from the server via the POP3 protocol, and then put them into the database. I work with .NET, win forms, C# language.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: See this question for the POP3 part:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c

Comment: already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c

Comment: @SimonMourier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c-sharp not found

Comment: @LucaTettamanti http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c-sharp not found

Comment: Now, undeleted question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275135/why-post-about-pop3-c-is-deleted?noredirect=1#comment109181_275135

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any built in pop3 feature in .net, only smtp outgoing.

There are several pop3 controls out there which you can purchase / download.

There are tons of results in Google that solve this problem:

- http://tinyurl.com/35892z8

It depends if you are willing to spend money or want it free.

Comment: I used OpenPop.NET and I am satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

you can use OpenPop.NET from NuGet.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenPop.NET/
http://hpop.sourceforge.net/