# C# Print Email Attachments

Tags: c#, email, printing, pop3

I need to Write a Programm in C# which can print Email-Attechments from Mail from Pop3-Mailbox.
But i dont know how i can connect to a Pop3-Server.

Comment: A Google search for "C# read pop3 email" seems to find some useful examples and libraries.

Comment: You can try searching before writing a question.
Try This one:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8607776/673707

Comment: Well, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6062/A-POP-Client-in-C-NET

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# POP3 protocol solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336978/c-sharp-pop3-protocol-solution)

Answer (score 0):

As @David [example1](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/40406-connecting-to-pop3-server/) 
[example2](https://www.emailarchitect.net/eagetmail/kb/csharp.aspx)

Use Googgle for it, and when you will have new questions- write to SO.