# Receive Gmail inbox through C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, gmail

I am implementing an asp.net/C# project where I would like to include a page where the admin can view emails from a gmail account. While googleing I found this [thread](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6062/A-POP3-Client-in-C-NET/?fid=33306&tid=3599886), but unfortunately its not working (for me). I was wondering if there's any other simpler solution to receive emails which is compatible with Gmail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading Email using Pop3 in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c-sharp)

Comment: maybe this article will help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17408/NET-Interop-for-Gadgets-A-C-GMail-Inbox-Reader-Ex

Comment: Why don't you accept the solution ? Please give a value for your question.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c-sharp), but if you click through to the [Floresense](http://www.floresense.com/resc_center/?art=1407) site, you'll see that the author has an example where they connect to GMail (pop.gmail.com).

Hope this helps.  Good luck!

Comment: I apologize for making a duplicate post, it wasn't my intention. Thanks a lot for your answer, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: Not a problem - no reason to apologize.  I hope this helps out.  That's the beauty of a community-run site -- we all try to maintain it.  :)  Good luck!!

Comment: Mark answered if you're satisfied with the answer