# How work with pop3 or IMap protocols in c# or in another language?

Tags: c#, email, smtp, imap, pop3

I want to get, delete... messges from my application (c# or another language) using POP3 or Imap in C# (or in another language), like in telnet. I know POP3 commands but don't know how use them in my application. Is there a library that can help me?

For example how can i connect to server with 110 port and send folowing command`
    RETR 1

Comment: Please refer to [this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the openpop.net library to manage them.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/