# Receive attachment via email and automatically move it to a pre defined folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm trying to implement a system where a client sends an attachment to say reports@abcorp.com and that attachment is automatically saved to a pre-defined folder so the file can be processed.

I already have the second part ready for processing files in that folder.  I'm just not sure how do I automate the first process of moving attached files from a email to that folder.

I'm not sure if I need to create a web service for this or may be use an email client and write a script to scan for emails with attachments and move that to a folder.  Please help.

Update: This process needs to take place on a virtual GoDaddy server. I wonder if there is a dropbox solution for implementing something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various closed and open source POP email libraries available - isn't that what you're looking for?

EDIT--

http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/?source=directory

[Reading Email using Pop3 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Possibly. I don't mind using POP as long as it gets the job done. Can you point me to those POP libraries?

Comment: @wackytacky99 have added some places to look