# Pop3Client error: "7bit is not supported encoding name"

Tags: c#, email, pop3

**I have an code that opens my mail box. This is the code:**

```
private Pop3Client GetPop3Client()
{
        Pop3Client popClient = new Pop3Client();
        popClient.Connect("smtp.xxxxxxxxx.xxxx.xx", 110, false);
        popClient.Authenticate("username", "passowrd");
        return popClient;
}
```

**So, in that line:**

```
Message message = popClient.GetMessage(1);
```

**This error occurs:**

> '7bit' is not a supported encoding name. Parameter name: name at
>   System.Globalization.EncodingTable.internalGetCodePageFromName(String
>   name) at System.Globalization.EncodingTable.GetCodePageFromName(String
>   name) at
>   OpenPop.Mime.Header.HeaderFieldParser.ParseCharsetToEncoding(String
>   characterSet) at OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart.ParseBodyEncoding(String
>   characterSet) at OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart..ctor(Byte[] rawBody,
>   MessageHeader headers) at
>   OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart.ParseMultiPartBody(Byte[] rawBody) at
>   OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart.ParseBody(Byte[] rawBody) at
>   OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart..ctor(Byte[] rawBody, MessageHeader headers)
>   at OpenPop.Mime.Message..ctor(Byte[] rawMessageContent, Boolean
>   parseBody) at OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client.GetMessage(Int32 messageNumber)
>   at DocumentCenter.Repository.ProcessMessage.ReadAllInMailBox() in
>   C:\dsn\net\project\project.Repository\ProcessMessage.cs:line 414

How to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading Email using Pop3 in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

Since [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) ([NuGet package here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/)) has a similar API to OpenPOP, you might try switching to MailKit instead as it does not have this problem (it properly deals with bad character encoding names when parsing messages).

If you don't want to change to MailKit, you'll need to edit the source code of OpenPOP and fix OpenPop.Mime.Header.HeaderFieldParser.ParseCharsetToEncoding() to properly handle bad charset names.